# dask scheduler OOM opening a large number of avro files

Tags: dask, avro

I'm trying to run a pipeline via dask on a cluster on gcp. The pipeline loads a lot of avro files from cloud storage (~5300 files with around 300MB each) like this

```py
bag = db.read_avro(
    'gcs://mybucket/myfiles-*.avro',
    blocksize=5000000
)
```

It then applies some transformations and saves the data back to cloud storage (as parquet files).

I've tested this pipeline with a fraction of the avro files and it works perfectly, but when I tell it to ingest all the files, the scheduler process sits at 100% CPU for a long time and at some point it runs out of memory (I have tried scaling my master node running the scheduler up to 64GB of RAM but that still does not suffice), while the workers are idling. I assume that the problem is that it has to create an excessive amount of tasks that are all held in RAM before being distributed to the workers.

Is this some sort of antipattern that I'm using when trying to open a very large number of files? If so, is there perhaps a built-in way to better cope with this or would I have to split the avro files manually?

Answer (score 1):

Avro with Dask at scale is not particularly well-trodden territory. There is no theoretical reason it should not work. You could inspect the contents of the graph to see if things are getting serialised there that are large, or if simply a massive number of tasks are being generated. If the former, it may be solvable, and you could raise an issue.

As you say, you may be able to keep the load on the scheduler down by processing sub-batches out of the total set of files at a time and waiting for completion.

Comment: I seem to have a talent for picking odd tools. So am I correct that if I let dask create the bag, I should not have to scatter any data to the workersmanually and it should not at first land on the scheduler? Is there any documentation how I would go about inspecting the graph contents?

Comment: Look at the `.visualize` method, `.dask` attribute (and its `.visualize`), which can also be cast to a `dict`.

Comment: I had a look at the graph and I couldn't make out anything special except that it gets very wide quite quickly. Do you think there's a chance that using parquet instead of avro would help or is working with 5-10TB of data simply out of scope for dask?

Comment: parquet is *certainly* better able to handle large amounts of data in parquet, especially if you mean to do dataframe-like operations (as opposed to row-by-row iteration)

Comment: So I did end up having to split the files manually. I still feel like there's something weird going on when opening a lot of avro files but I'm too green with the `dask` internals to figure out what is really happening.